# VS17 and TFS 17 Build requirments

Tags: c#, tfs, devops

We are using TFS 2017 to manage our code that is developed using Visual Studio 17.  So I created a new WPF desktop App, that when run gives you only the main window.  I am now trying to create the MSI install package from with in TFS under the build tab.

```
*Manual Build of XXXXX-.NET Desktop-CI (1) (XXXXXX)
```

Ran for 0.4 minutes (ELANCON), completed at Sat 03/09/2019 02:14 PM
Request Summary
Request 242
XXXXX, Stephan M
Completed 
Summary
| Build
2 error(s), 2 warning(s) 
Build - 2 error(s), 2 warning(s) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1098):C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1098,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'*.

the other error I see is

```
Issues
Build 
Visual Studio version '15.0' not found. Falling back to version '14.0'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1098, 5) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1098,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
Directory 'D:\TFSVSOWork\91\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
```

I have a book on order that comes out at the end of the month, I cant seem to find a link to how to do this without using Azure. My Next steps after this is Automated testing.

How do I build?

Comment: "The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"" did you check whether the TFS server has .NET 4.7.2 installed?

Comment: Where? I only have access to the TFS frontend.  Anything behind the curtain for install seems to be hidden.  There has to be a way from within TFS to see the actual file folders on the server.

Comment: No, why would there be? That's a terrible security problem. Talk to whoever is in charge of the administration of your TFS, we cannot help you

Comment: No, I didn't say anything even close to that. You are using a **hosted** TFS, that means that **someone** from your company or a third party controls that TFS, updates it and whatever. You have to ask **that someone** to install .NET 4.7.2 on that server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this I had been enlightened to the fact that a Build Agent was not created for me.  I was using someone else's Agent that was specific to them and I may have not had rights to the area's it was trying to access.  Having good documentation when creating a process is key when someone else needs to use what you have built.